# Making text fade in/out on button click in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs

I have a random quote generator written in React: https://codepen.io/1000mileworld/pen/RwNMwKE

When I click the new quote button, I would like the previous quote to fade out and the new quote to fade in.

I was trying to use some jQuery that changed the opacity to 0 before setting new state and then return opacity back to 1 afterwards. I probably have to do this outside handleClick() somewhere but not sure how.

```
handleClick() { 
 $("#text").animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500);

 const quote = getRandomQuote();
 this.setState({
   text: quote.text,
   author: quote.author
 });

 $("#text").animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500);    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general it's not recommended that you query the DOM (ie using selectors to pick an element to call `$.animate()` on) when rendering those elements with React.

Perhpas you could consider another approach that by-passes JQuery all together and instead uses CSS transitions and React to achieve the equvilant fade transition?

Something like this might work for you:

**JSX**

```
const FADE_DURATION = 1000;

class Application extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {     
        text: quote.text,
        author: quote.author,

        // Add extra state to control fading
        fadeTransition : null,
        fadeState : "fade-in",
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }

    handleClick(){ 

    // Create a timer that runs after quote
    // fades out
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {

        // After current quote faded out, fetch
        // next quote and display
        const quote = getRandomQuote();

        this.setState({
        text: quote.text,
        author: quote.author,
        // Apply additional state to control
        // fading transition
        fadeTransition : null,
        fadeState : 'fade-in'
        });    
    }, FADE_DURATION);

    // Stop any existing transition
    clearTimeout(this.state.fadeTransition);

    // Update state to perform the fade out from
    // current quote
    this.setState({ 
        fadeState : 'fade-out', 
        fadeTransition : timeout 
    });
    }

    render() {
    return (
        <div className={`fade-wrapper ${this.state.fadeState}`} 
                style={{ transitionDuration: `${FADE_DURATION}ms`}}>
        <Display text={this.state.text} 
                    author={this.state.author} 
                    click={this.handleClick} />
        </div>
    );
    }
}
```

**CSS**

```css
/* Add this to existing css */
.fade-wrapper {
    transition:opacity ease-in-out;
}
.fade-out {
    opacity:0;  
}
.fade-in {
    opacity:1;
}
```

[Here's a working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-cloud-nd1vv) (sorry the CSS is a little broken) - hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks this worked for me! I can take care of the CSS haha

Comment: So I actually have a question on how the timer clears. Suppose you click the button twice really fast so that the 1st fade in isn't complete. Since you're clearing the variable 'timeout', how does it know to clear the 1st one and not the 2nd click's fade in? Just confused because shouldn't the 2nd click redefine 'timeout'? I understand setTimeout is async but not sure if that includes variable defining as well

Comment: In the case you describe, the idea is to ensure that any old time out that's queued to trigger the "fade in" is cancelled, before we schedule a new one. In the code above we first schedule a function to be called that sets the "fade in" animation. If this gets called in the future, the fade in will commense. We then cancel any previous timer that was scheduled using `clearTimeout` as shown above. A timer may not actually exist on the current state variable `this.state.fadeTransition`, but we call it anyway, just incase. Next, we initiate the `fade-out`. All animation is ..

Comment: .. actually handled by the browser. That's the nice thing about CSS transitions - if a CSS transition is midway through the property transition for an element, and we go and change a class or style on that element, the browser will automagically handle this for us - no addtional work to manage a "half finishied" transition is required on our part. Not sure if this helps at all, but hopefully it's filled in a few gaps in my answer :-)

Comment: so to check my understanding, in the 1st click this.state.fadeTransition is set to timeout during fade out of the previous quote but in the 2nd click since this.state.fadeTransition gets set after clearTimeout the timeout variable still refers to the 1st click's when it's passed to clearTimeout?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the callback from animate, and set the state there. Something like:

```
    $( "#txt" ).animate({
    opacity: 0,
  }, 2000, function() {
    that.setState({text:"world"});
    $( "#txt" ).animate({
    opacity: 1,
  }, 2000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
```

You'll need to be aware that the scope of 'this' will need to be handled within the callback. I just did that=this in the example just to demonstrate the usage of the callback.

https://jsfiddle.net/pythagoras2357/8zarn94j/9/

https://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: I couldn't figure out what to replace 'this' with. Tried Application.setState but got an error saying that setState is not a function. However, solved problem another way